# Java reflection handling library changes

Tags: java, android, reflection, dex

Ok so I have an Android app and I started creating an addon system for the app so developers can code content providers that the app can then use to generate different content, I will not go through the whole procedure but everything works fine like so:

1)
I created a library called `com.myaddonlib` that I imported in my project in this library there is an interface and different objects.

2)
Now a developer can create a simple Java project on his end, import the library `com.myaddonlib`, and implement the interface on his main class which have methods that return different objects from the library.

3) 
Back on the android app, I can load the .jar file created by the developer (after the classes.dex is added to the jar file) and with the android DexClassLoader I can load the implemented interface like so :

```
DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(jarFilePath, tempDirectory, null, context.getClass().getClassLoader());     
Class classToLoad = classloader.loadClass("com.apackage.Addon");
```

where `Addon` is the class created by the addon developer that implements the interface from the library residing in a package named `com.apackage`.
I can then cast the interface from the library `com.myaddonlib` to a new instance of `classToLoad` and call the functions that the addon developer implemented.

Now here is the issue lets say I decided to update the addon library and remove one of the variables from a class, meaning that the addon's class is now different from the class in the updated library (used in the app). Even when the changed variable is not used something causes the app to crash without any error. Just the fact that both classes are different (even when the only difference is just a missing variable ) causes something to malfunction. Now this is not an easy procedure to explain so I would understand that given my bad english some have trouble following. 
My issue is that I need to know how to avoid this crash due to the change of the library on one of both ends. And also how java treats object changes in a situation like this

Comment: Assuming addon update is being done at runtime, Android Studio's instant-run tackles kinda similar problem. Try to read more about it, for example [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f).

Comment: @Alex instant run is a development tool as far as I know and cant be used in production and I even doubt it should, I am talking about loading addons in a seperate .dex file as explained above, rewriting the apps dex depending on the loaded addon seems to me to be a big security risk

Comment: I didn't meant that instant-run is a solution for your aforementioned problem. I'm just saying that instant-run tackles the issue of reloading classes at runtime, which is similar to what you're looking for (as far as I understand) - and by looking at how it works, you'll hopefully be able to get ideas to build your own solution.

Comment: @Alex yes I see what you mean thanks for the proposal, but the thing is I already managed to get everything done the only part that causes issue is the fact that the addon dex has a copy of the class thats in the android project and if there is a difference in any one of them this causes an issue.

Comment: Is there a chance that you can provide a simple example that will illustrate your problem (initial apk, addon dex, and then modified apk)? No need for your full-blown solution, just the relevant parts.

Comment: @Alex what do you mean by modified apk ?

Comment: Sorry, modified addon dex.

Answer (score 2):

My solution does not solve the problem, but instead makes sure it will never happen. The problem you are describing resembles the classic server-client problem. You have a server (in your case the app you are developing) and clients (the addons that are written by the developers). You can define an interface with many functions and pass data in binary structures. This would be more efficient from a traffic/parsing perspective, however whenever you change the API on the server you will have to update all the clients (or else crashes or other issues might occur).

So to solve this problem on the server-client many choose to use HTTP calls with [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) objects that describe the data. Although this way is less efficient, it allows adding APIs and supporting many client versions at the same time.

Using this approach in Android is quite simple. Define an API with two functions and a single interface:

```
public String sendDataToLibrary(String jsonString) {
   // Parse data, perform operation and return a JSON string as the result
}

public interface GetDataFromLibrary {
   String onDataFromLibrary(String jsonString);
}

public void init startLibrary(GetDataFromLibrary callback) {
   // Set callback in library and call it whenever you have data that needs to be sent out from the library asynchronously 
}
```

As you can see, if you implement this interface, you can pass any data around between the library and addons and it will never change so no crashes would occur. An improvement can be to force passing version number to allow the library to support multi-versioning).

Comment: hello, thanks for your suggestion, passing data as JSON would cause confusion, I believe the issue with reflection is the fact that when the addon receives an object from the app when the addon tries to cast the Class from the librairy to that object and the definition of the class is not the same on both ends it crashes. When using Serializable if we set the same `serialVersionUID` changes in the variables dont cause Java to not recognize the class anymore but just ignore the changes, but this doesnt work in this case so I am sure there is a way to get it done

Comment: An alternative to JSON is to pass a Bundle object. Maybe that would be less confusing. The important thing is to avoid casting as the objects might not be correct.

Comment: I could pass a serialized object and deserialize it on the addons end snd then cast it with the same SerialVersionUID but then again users wouldnt know which object they received so the deserialization process would also be confusing.